# user_passes_test: raise exception if user does not pass

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-1.4

I am trying to define a decorator to check if the user has admin certain privileges:

```
def admin_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_staff and u.is_authenticated() and not Association.objects.filter(admins=u).exists(),
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

The aim is to use this throught the views. Particularly, I am using it in a class-based view:

```
class MyCBV(CreateView):
    @method_decorator(admin_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyCBV, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that this view is loaded via AJAX, so the redirect doesn't happen. Also, the HTTP status the view returns is success even when the user authentication fails, so the client (JS) has no way of telling when the action really succeeded or not.

I usually have trouble understanding decorators and Django authentication, so my question is: how can I raise an exception (preferably the `PermissionDenied` exception) when the authentication decoration function fails?

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.9+, you can use the [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) instead of a decorator, and set `raise_exception` to `True`.

Since you are using Django 1.4, which is insecure and obsolete, you won't be able to do this. There isn't an option to make `user_passes_test` raise `PermissionDenied` rather than redirect. You could either try to detect the redirect in your JavaScript, or look at the `user_passes_test` source code and implement something similar that returns the response you want.

Comment: Is there any way I can set up a different decorator to raise the exception? As I mentioned, I am not too proficient at developing decorators, but I feel like I could do it if I could understand just one thing: how is the user passed to `user_passes_test`? It seems a bit magical. If I can figure out how to fetch the request's user from the decorator, I'd be good to go.

Comment: You can write your own decorator that raises the exception. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4202ed243710926c3f059d848304145bd6b89225/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L10) for `user_passes_test` would be a good place to start. The `_wrapped_view` created in the decorator takes `request` as it's first argument. It can than access the user using `request.user`.